# I want my discord bot to respond to a certain word which may be included in a sentence sent by the user. (python 3.8.2)

Tags: python, discord

So currently my code is like this:

```
if message.content == "hello":      
     user = message.author 
     await message.channel.send('hello {}'.format(user.mention))
```

But I want the bot to respond to a specific word that may be in the sentence instead of a message that contains only "hello" and I don't know how to go about it. Any help?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead check if your desired string is in the message content:

```
if 'hello' in message.content:      
     user = message.author 
     await message.channel.send('hello {}'.format(user.mention))
```